# cannot clear previous text on jquery modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to clear the previous text on the modal popup but I cannot do that I have searched internet but couldn't found any appropriate solution to my problem, I'm sharing my code please guide me

**JQUERY:**

```
$('table').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    $( "#popup" ).dialog({
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).html(clone);
        },
        buttons: {
            "Okay": function () {

                $(this).dialog("close");

            },           
        },        
    }); 
    $("#sumresult").clone(true).appendTo("div.ui-dialog-buttonpane").show();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Part</th>
   <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>New part</td>
    <td>231134</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>New part</td>
    <td>231134</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="popup" title="Table Preview"></div>
<div id="sumresult">12390.21</div>
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hg9NJ/3/

when I open `modal` again and again it will show the same value multiple times as I open.

Comment: You clone and append `#sumresult` to `div.ui-dialog-buttonpane` on every click.

Comment: thanks for the comment but how i can clear the previous input? i want the sumresult value in popup modal

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/hg9NJ/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clear the html of the popup

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hg9NJ/8)

```
$('table').on('click', function(e){
     $(".ui-widget-content").html(""); // clear html 
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    $( "#popup" ).dialog({
        open: function( event, ui ) {


            $(this).html(clone);
        },
        buttons: {
            "Okay": function () {

                $(this).dialog("close");

            },           
        },        
    }); 
    $("#sumresult").clone(true).appendTo("div.ui-dialog-buttonpane").show();
});
```

Comment: i have few other questions is there any way i can just tag u and want u to help me on those questions?

Comment: dont think so, but feel free to comment here and link me to a new question

Comment: i will link u here. because i just found u brilliant and quick here